# form get method not working in opera browser

Tags: forms, methods, get, opera

Why forms submited using get method is not working in opera browser?

```
<form method="get" action="">
```

I am submiting to same page

```
<form method="get" action="">
  <table class="search_form_table" width="428" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >

     <tr>
        <td width="150">Order Number</td>
        <td><input name="order_number" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Start Date</td>
        <td><input class="search_date_fields" name="date_from" /> End date : <input class="search_date_fields" name="date_to" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><input class="subimit_button search_button_width" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: put the rest of the code

Comment: code added, please check

Comment: there no problem with the form, why not using post

Comment: Get is working in firefox. post is working

Answer (score 2):

If this is the same problem I thought I had, it's not that GET doesn't work.  It's because the browser hides the form name/value pairs in the query string in the Location bar.  If you actually go to the location bar and hilite the URL that you submitted to, you'll see the form parameters in the query string.  I hate this, but it is the way Opera does it.  :-/

Comment: I believe you used to be able to turn this "feature" off in settings (to show the full URL), however, with Opera 16...17 this "feature" is back and there seems to be no way to disable it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

submitting GET forms certainly works in Opera. Copying this code to a file and submitting it creates exactly the same URL as in Chrome. Hence, your problem must be something else. Without more information it's impossible to tell what your problem really is.

Comment: Yes, GET parameters work in Opera, I just checked it, it won't be so popular if it din't :) :)